# Sed on lines matching a given number of specific character

Tags: awk, sed, xargs

My file:

```
Nicole,Foo,senior,Lexington
John,Doe,junior,Chicago
John,Fool,True,junior,Detroit
Lara,True,Fool,senior,Miami
```

What I'd like: remove the second comma in line when there is four instead of three commas, like so:

```
Nicole,Foo,senior,Lexington
John,Doe,junior,Chicago
John,Fool True,junior,Detroit
Lara,True Fool,senior,Miami
```

What I tried:

To detect the lines with four commas:

```
awk -F, '{print NF-1; next; print $0}' myfile
```

To remove the second comma in a line:

```
sed 's/,/ /2' myfile
```

What I still can't do:
Combine the two commands and **apply the sed command only to lines with 4 commas**. I suspect it could be done with xargs somehow but I don't know how to handle it with such conditionnal statement.

Maybe someone could give me some direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/\([^,]*,\)\{4\}/s/,/ /2' file
```

When 4 sequences of non-comma string followed by a comma are found, replace second comma with a space.

Answer (score 0):

In awk (I'd use `sed` for this one):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }               # separators
NF==5 {                            # for five-fielded records
    for(i=2;i<NF;i++)              # starting from the second
        $i=(i==2?$i " ":"") $(i+1) # append or replace with the next field
    NF=4                           # reduce the field count for those records
}1' file
Nicole,Foo,senior,Lexington
John,Doe,junior,Chicago
John,Fool True,junior,Detroit
Lara,True Fool,senior,Miami
```

Answer (score 0):

try also following awk:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(NF>4){if(i==2){$i=$i " "$(i+1)};if(i==3){continue}};printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"":",");}print ""}'   Input_file
```

OR

```
awk -F, '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
  if(NF>4){
  if(i==2){
    $i=$i " "$(i+1)
  };
  if(i==3){
   continue
  }
  };
  printf("%s%s",$i,i==NF?"":",");
  }
  print ""
}'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk '/Fool,|True,/{$0=gensub(/,/," ",2)}1' file

Nicole,Foo,senior,Lexington
John,Doe,junior,Chicago
John,Fool True,junior,Detroit
Lara,True Fool,senior,Miami
```